# Will I need to pay tax on my foreign income on my return to the UK if I have spent a total of15 months out of the country? (August 2017-October2018)

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I am looking to return to the UK from the UAE October this year. I will have been away from the UK for 15months in total and whilst I have been away I have been counted as a non uk resident as I am employed and work full time in the UAE. Wanting advice on whether I will need to pay tax on the money I earned abroad on my return as it is part of the new tax year? Thankyou

Comment: How many days did you spend in the UK in the tax year 2017-2018? Whether it's 183 days or more could be important (https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence)

Comment: Sorry, that should be "how many days will you spend in the UK in the tax year 2018-19?"

Comment: As Ganesh has commented, if you spend more that half the year (183 days) in the UK, then you will need to declare all of your worldwide income for that year.  The good news is that as of Dec2016, the UK and UAE have a tax treaty so you will not be double taxed.  However, if the UK tax rate payable is higher than that of the UAE, then you will be required to pay the difference to the UK tax authorities.

Comment: Thanks for replying! In the tax year 17-18 I spent 140 days in the UK in total. For tax year 18-19 if I return to the uk to work in the January I will have spent 162 days in the UK.  Is it the best advice to remain out of the country until the new tax year? And if so can this be done via travel or do I need to be employed abroad?